# st_write refuses to write characters with quotes in R

Tags: r, csv, character, r-sf

Using the sf package in R, I am reading a .shp file and export the data .csv file. My problem is, that characters get exported without quotes.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc <- head(nc)
nc$NAME_text <- as.character(nc$NAME)
nc <- nc %>% select(AREA, NAME, NAME_text, FIPS, CRESS_ID)
str(nc)
st_write(nc, "test.csv")
```

The NAME (factor) and NAME_text (character) columns contain quotes in the Console (str(nc)).

```
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ AREA     : num  0.114 0.061 0.143 0.07 0.153 0.097
 $ NAME     : Factor w/ 100 levels "Alamance","Alexander",..: 5 3 86 27 66 46
 $ NAME_text: chr  "Ashe" "Alleghany" "Surry" "Currituck" ...
 $ FIPS     : Factor w/ 100 levels "37001","37003",..: 5 3 86 27 66 46
 $ CRESS_ID : int  5 3 86 27 66 46
 $ geometry :sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 6; first list element: List of 1
```

However, in the exported .csv file, the characters in "NAME_text" column have no quotes. What am I missing here?

```
AREA,NAME,FIPS,CRESS_ID
0.114,Ashe,"37009","5"
0.061,Alleghany,"37005","3"
0.143,Surry,"37171","86"
0.07,Currituck,"37053","27"
0.153,Northampton,"37131","66"
0.097,Hertford,"37091","46"
```

Comment: The CSV format isn't really well defined, but generally quotes aren't needed in data like yours.  Some readers treat quoted entries as character even if they look numeric (like your FIPS and CRESS_ID columns), but that's not very common.  R only uses quotes to mark commas as part of an entry rather than a field separator.

Comment: I would like to specify somewhere, that the exported characters have quotes. Is that possible?

Comment: `st_write` uses code internal to the package, and that code doesn't appear to offer an option to make that choice.  You may have to write using `st_write`, then read the `.csv` file and write it again using `utils::write.csv` or some similar function.  The `utils::write.csv` function has a `quotes` argument that controls what gets quoted.

Comment: Alternatively, you could convert the dataset to a dataframe by removing the geometry `st_geometry(nc) <- NULL` and write it out using `write.csv`.